# PHP/MySQL to PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, css, pdo, content-management-system

I'm very new to PHP/Mysql and I naturally have a few questions. I was following a youtube tutorial on creating a simple dynamic website that pulls data content from a MySQL database then displays the content on a single PHP index page. I followed this tutorial to the point where I was using PHP/MySQL to connect to the DB, run a query, fetch the query using a fetch_assoc array. but nothing would display in the body of the page. During the trouble shooting process I was advised that I should be using PDO instead of the older MySQL methods. Can someone decipher my current "older" MySQL code and translate it into the proper PDO coding approach so that I can learn to grasp PDO, since it is the future I should start to understand it now :)

### index.php:

```
<?php
// Setup document:
include('config/setup.php');

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title><?php echo $page_title; ?> - test site</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">

</head>

<body>

 <div class="wrap_overall">

    <div class="header">
       <?php include('template/header.php'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="nav_main">
        <?php include('template/nav_main.php'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <?php //include('content/'.$pg.'.php');
        // the database connection, our query
        $q = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE page = '$pg' AND status = 1 LIMIT 1";
        $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
         if (!$r) {
         die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
         }

        $page = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r);

        echo '<h1>'.$page['title'].'</h1>';
        echo '<div class="content_body">'.$page['body'].'</div>';

         ?>    
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <?php include('template/footer.php'); ?>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

### setup.php:

```
<?php ## Setup Document
// host(or location of the database), username, password, database name
//Variables for connecting to your database.
//These variable values come from your hosting account.
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "atomcmsadmin";
$password = "uniCi2i";
$dbname = "Atom_CMS";
//Connecting to your database
$dbc = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password) OR DIE ("Unable to 
connect to database! Please try again later.");
mysqli_select_db($dbname);
//include('functions/sandbox.php');
if ($_GET ['page'] == '') {
    $pg = 'home';} 
else {
    $pg = $_GET ['page']; }
$page_title = get_page_title($dbc, $pg);
?>
```

### sandbox.php

```
<?php
// Sandbox Functions

function get_page ($dbc, $pg) {

    // the database connection, our query
    $q = "SELECT title FROM pages WHERE type = 1, page = '$pg' AND status = 1 LIMIT 1";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

    $page = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r);

    echo '<h1>'.$page['title'].'</h1>';
    echo '<div class="content">'.$page['body'].'</div>';        
}
function get_page_title ($dbc, $pg) {

    $q = "SELECT title FROM pages WHERE type = 1, page = '$pg' AND status = 1 LIMIT 1";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

    $page = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r);

    return $page['title'];      
}
?>
```

Comment: No. Nobody is going to rewrite your code with no attempts shown on your part so far. Just switching to PDO is not useful advise either. It's about bound parameters, which simplify things and avoid SQL exploits often implicitly. Mysqli also supports those, but you're still using unsanitized SQL interpolation. See a tutorial such as http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers first.

Comment: { wasn't looking for someone to do the work for me. I made sure to word my question as to merely point me in the right direction. Paulo has given me a good starting point. Thanks for the tutorial it should provide more insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think no one will do the job for you. But I can help you help yourself:

From your code, you'll need to learn these PDO methods:

- [PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php)

  You'll replace `mysqli_connect()` and `mysqli_select_db()` with that.
- [PDO::prepare()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php), [PDOStatement::bindValue()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) and [PDOStatement::execute()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

  You'll replace `mysqli_query()` with them.
- [PDOStatement::fetch()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

  You'll replace `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` with that.
- [PDO::errorCode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorcode.php) and [PDO::errorInfo()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php)

  You might want to use one of them or both to cover errors.

Also take a look at [PDO book](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) on the PHP manual. You'll learn all the stuff more easier than you think! Good luck!

Comment: this is the easiest way to switch on PDO. very helpful information.

Answer (score 1):

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

all you need to change is setting up the connection, check out the tutorial for the syntax

interacting with the database is still mostly the same

Comment: Thank you! :) I'll take a look at the tutorial. It should help.